# Activate python virtualenv and runserver in bat file with windows terminal

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-terminal

I'm trying to create a bat file to open windows terminal, activate an environment and run a server. After some attemps the best I've got is this:

```
wt.exe cmd -NoExit -c "c:\Users\me\Desktop\'myProyectVirtualenv'\virtualenv\Scripts\activate.ps1;cd C:\Users\me\Desktop\myProyect\;python manage.py runserver"
```

But windows terminal activate the environment in a tab and in other tab throw this error:

```
[error 0x80070002 when launching `"C:\Users\me\Desktop\myproyect\;python manage.py runserver"']
```

I think that maybe the command after the environment activation is not properly 'passed' to the environment... but really I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`-NoExit -c` both look like *powershell* flags, not `cmd` ones. That might be a place to start.

I'd recommend just taking the entire script you've got there:

```
c:\Users\me\Desktop\'myProyectVirtualenv'\virtualenv\Scripts\activate.ps1;cd C:\Users\me\Desktop\myProyect\;python manage.py runserver"
```

and putting it into a `.bat` file like:

```
powershell -f c:\Users\me\Desktop\'myProyectVirtualenv'\virtualenv\Scripts\activate.ps1
cd C:\Users\me\Desktop\myProyect\
python manage.py runserver"
```

then running that with `wt.exe foo.bat`